# comparar una o dos filas de diferentes tablas y obtener los registros iguales

Tags: sql, tablas

buenos días esta es mi situación:

tengo 2 tablas iguales con los siguientes campos 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven son iguales pero tienen cada una diferentes registros y algunos iguales lo que quiero es hacer una consulta donde me muestre los registros que sean IGUALES ejemplo que me seleccione solo los que son MAC_1
y si es posible que cumpla con 2 condiciones como por ejemplo que me seleccione que sea MAC_1 y Switch 1 (aclaro que MAC puede tener diferentes Switch)

les agradezco su colaboración

Comment: Que tal, Puedes usar los [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) para unir 1 o mas tablas, te anexo la documentación para referencias

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma puedes obtener la unión de ambas tablas:

```
SELECT Mac, IP FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Mac, IP FROM table2;
```

La anterior consulta te devolvería 2 registros únicamente puesto que, UNION evita que haya registros duplicados en el resultado final. Es decir, se eliminan las filas en las que los valores de los campos se dupliquen. El problema sería que no podríamos definir con la anterior consulta cual de todos los registros de MAC_1 o MAC_2 va a dejar y por ende el valor de IP podría ser cualquiera.

Si desearas obtener la unión total de los registros sin importar que se dupliquen, tendrías que usar UNION ALL.

```
SELECT Mac, IP FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT Mac, IP FROM table2;
```

La anterior consulta te devolvería 5 registros.